# Make changes in one Column while keeping the dataframe unchanged

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to make changes in 'Column C' of the dataframe(df) while keeping other values unchanged in the dataframe using python.

Condition: If any value in 'Column C' < 5 & 'Column C' > 15,change it to 'NaN'

Current Dataframe:

```
Index  Column A  Column B  Column C
0        6        12         15
1        8         8         2
2       10        14         6
3        9        16         3
4        4         3         7
5        2        18         7
```

Expected Dataframe Output:

```
Index  Column A  Column B  Column C
0        6        12         NaN
1        8         8         NaN
2       10        14         6
3        9        16         NaN
4        4         3         7
5        2        18         7
```

I tried to use the `df.apply()` method as shown below but it messed up my indexes. Could you please help?

```
df.loc[df['Column C'].apply(lambda x:np.nan if x <5 and x>15 else x)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for formatting my codes in seconds! Very much appreciated.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis yes the below answer was helpful. I have accepted the answer by ticking on left. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. In general, only use `pd.Series.apply` where a calculation cannot be vectorised. In addition, you require an `or` (|) statement, not `and`, since no value can be simultaneously below 5 and above 15.

```
df.loc[(df.C < 5) | (df.C > 15), 'C'] = np.nan
```

Comment: @christina, SO is an interesting sort of place in which thanking somebody with words is not generally desired. Please thank people that help you by accepting the answer you determine is correct and giving +1 to any answer or comment you find helpful. An answer can be accepted by clicking the big check mark to the left of the Answer, under the Answer's score.